# How do I define a computed field equal to the concatenation of two fields of my custom entity?

Tags: entities, 8

I have a custom entity (Person) with these fields: ID, nom, prenom, telephoneportable, estactive, userID, created, changed. I created it with baseFieldDefinitions.

I want to have a computed field nomprenom = nom ." ".prenom
Here is the corresponding code:

```
$fields['nomprenom'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')  
  ->setLabel(t('Nom et Prénom'))  
  ->setComputed(TRUE)  
  ->setClass('\Drupal\association\NomPrenom');
```

The code of class 'NomPrenom' is here:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\association\NomPrenom.
 */

namespace Drupal\association;

use Drupal\Component\Utility\String;
use Drupal\Core\TypedData\DataDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedDataInterface;
use Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedData;

/**
 * A computed property for defining 'Nom Prénom'.
 */
class NomPrenom extends TypedData {

  /**
   * Cached processed value.
   *
   * @var string|null
   */
  protected $processed = NULL;

  /**
   * Implements \Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedDataInterface::getValue().
   */
  public function getValue($langcode = NULL) {
    if ($this->processed !== NULL) {
      return $this->processed;
    }

    $this->processed = $this->get('nom')->value ." ". $this->get('prenom')->value;
    return $this->processed;
  }

  /**
   * Implements \Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedDataInterface::setValue().
   */
  public function setValue($value, $notify = TRUE) {
    $this->processed = $value;

    // Notify the parent of any changes.
    if ($notify && isset($this->parent)) {
      $this->parent->onChange($this->name);
    }
  }

}
```

When I try to add a new Person, I get a PHP Fatal error:

> Call to undefined method Drupal\association\NomPrenom::setLangcode()

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I found this in ContentEntityBase.php 499 (but you could show us the whole error log):

I think the case is the following: your field is translatable (you didn't set it's not, and I tihnk the default is TRUE).

```
else {
  $field_langcode = $langcode;
}
**$field->setLangcode($field_langcode);**
$this->fields[$name][$langcode] = $field;
```

What I don't understand here: how basefield definition allows you to add a class which doesn't inherit / implements the right class / interface. I think it's a core bug?

You should either:
- add set language method, with a languagecode property
- set your computed field untranslatable

Comment: I have the same problem, but even when I use setTranslatable(FALSE) on the BaseFieldDefinition, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were following the examples in this article:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2112677

Note that one major difference is that the above article talks about computed properties in a (custom) field type, whereas you are trying to use a computed property in a custom entity. I don't know whether the latter is possible – I would like to know that myself.

However, from the above I expect that there is a feasible workaround that you could use: define a custom field type (e.g. called `name`) that defines two regular stored fields (`firstname` and `lastname`), as well as one computed property (`fullname`). You should then be able to create an instance of this field type in your entity's `baseFieldDefinitions()`.

Comment: It's definitely possible to add a computed field to a custom entity type. The article unfortunately starts with an example that shows a custom *property* on a field, but what's actually implemented is a  computed field on a custom entity ("profile").

Comment: This article might be helpful: https://cornel.co/article/entity-reference-computed-field-example-drupal
It shows a complex example how to use this on entities.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies probably in the definition:

```
$fields['nomprenom'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')  
  ->setLabel(t('Nom et Prénom'))  
  ->setComputed(TRUE)  
  ->setClass('\Drupal\association\NomPrenom');
```

The [example on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/dynamicvirtual-field-values-using-computed-field-property-classes) isn't very clear here, but `setClass` is **not** the class that computes the value. `setClass` is the `ItemList` class that is defined later in the article to work around a bug in core (`\Drupal\mymodule\CurrentCompanyLinkItemList`).

The matching of the field definition and the class happens in `BaseFieldDefinition::create('my_new_field')`. This should be a unique identifier for your new field, not simply `string` etc.

In your class, you set the same as the id in the FieldType annotation:

```
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "my_new_field",
 *   ...
 * )
```

Also note that the class that implements the FieldType must be in this namespace:

`namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Field\FieldType;`